# SoundPool audio stream type?

Tags: android, soundpool

I have one question. Can i use any of audio stream type `(STREAM_MUSIC, STREAM_RING, STREAM_ALARM, STREAM_SYSTEM, etc..)` on my *SoundPoolActivity*,
to control *SoundPool* audio volume from example, "Alarm volume". Using

```
SoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STREAM_ALARM        The audio stream for alarms
STREAM_DTMF         The audio stream for DTMF Tones
STREAM_MUSIC        The audio stream for music playback
STREAM_NOTIFICATION The audio stream for notifications
STREAM_RING         The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_SYSTEM       The audio stream for system sounds
STREAM_VOICE_CALL   The audio stream for phone calls
```

refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24655221/1660986 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html