# Android ToneGenerator startTone() very slow on the first call

Tags: java, android, performance, tone-generator

I'm calling `ToneGenerator.startTone()` repeatedly to issue short bursts of sound. But on the first call, it blocks for a long period of time. So the first burst is way too long. Here's an example:

Member variables:

```
private ToneGenerator mDTMFPlayer
```

In the constructor:

```
mDTMFPlayer = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, TONE_RELATIVE_VOLUME);
```

In a `Thread` started by `OnClickListener.onClick()`:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
Log.d(TAG,"After 1st: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
try { Thread.sleep(160); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
Log.d(TAG,"After 2nd: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
try { Thread.sleep(160); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
Log.d(TAG,"After 3rd: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
try { Thread.sleep(160); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();
```

Here's the output, with execution time of `startTone()` in milliseconds:

```
11-16 18:07:35.885 16927-17977/com.my.project D/Ring: After 1st: 454
11-16 18:07:36.502 16927-17977/com.my.project D/Ring: After 2nd: 0
11-16 18:07:36.672 16927-17977/com.my.project D/Ring: After 3rd: 1
```

The first call is blocking for almost half a second which is way too long for what I need. Any calls after that makes the blocking go away for a while. What's weird is that if I wait a bit and try again, it's slow again. There seems to be a period after which the blocking comes back.

Please advise.

Comment: How long is "a bit"? IOW, is this a per-process issue, where "a bit" is after your process was terminated and, by user action, was re-created?

Comment: No, the process continues, I wait less than a second and then and I click on the button again which calls onClick() and starts a separate thread (I don't want to block on the GUI thread) and calls startTone() again.

Comment: Well `startTone()` just calls a `native` method (see [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-cts-8.0_r4/media/java/android/media/ToneGenerator.java)), so I'm not sure that there's a lot that you can do about it.

Comment: If it wasn't native I probably would have found the cause already. :)

Comment: Point. Sorry if my comment implied otherwise -- as much as anything, my comment was for the next person to run into this problem, if you don't get an answer.

Comment: don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` is causing this. The behavior on my devise is similar to yours. After i run app it has long init for the first `startTone()` call. If i exit and enter app it can be fast for all 3 calls. But it will show same "slow, fast, fast" result if some system sound plays before the app starts.

So i suppose it has something to do with stream switching/blocking, because with `AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION` it takes only 4-10 msecs on my device. Also can read more info here: [What is the difference between AudioManager's stream types at low level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24652747/1032167)

Consider this code:

```
for (int i = -1; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("AudioSystem stream " + i);
    mDTMFPlayer = new ToneGenerator(i, TONE_RELATIVE_VOLUME);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
    Log.d(TAG, "After 1st: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    try {Thread.sleep(160);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
    Log.d(TAG, "After 2nd: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    try {Thread.sleep(160);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mDTMFPlayer.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_0);
    Log.d(TAG, "After 3rd: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    try {Thread.sleep(160);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    mDTMFPlayer.stopTone();
    mDTMFPlayer.release();
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream -1 STREAM_DEFAULT
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 8
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 0 STREAM_VOICE_CALL
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 325
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 1 STREAM_SYSTEM
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 17
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 2
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 3
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 2 STREAM_RING
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 28
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 2
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 3 STREAM_MUSIC
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 19
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 4 STREAM_ALARM
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 28
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 5 STREAM_NOTIFICATION
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 16
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 6 STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 332
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 2
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 7 STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 324
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 1
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 1
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 8 STREAM_DTMF
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 26
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 2
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 4
I/System.out: AudioSystem stream 9 STREAM_TTS
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 1st: 12
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 2nd: 4
D/com.example.MainActivity: After 3rd: 2
```

Btw, if you want to research related C sourse code you can look at [android_media_ToneGenerator.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/jni/android_media_ToneGenerator.cpp), [ToneGenerator.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libaudioclient/include/media/ToneGenerator.h), [ToneGenerator.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libaudioclient/ToneGenerator.cpp) [AudioService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/00ccd5d026fcd0e4b9d27dc5a9ffa13ca0408449/media/java/android/media/AudioService.java)

Comment: In the end I used the STREAM_DTMF which is actually made for that, and there's NO delay at all. Perfect solution. Thanks for your answer. Will give you the bounty for sure.

Comment: How long should the duration of startTone actually be? 50 ms? 150 ms?  What's the default/standard?